# Prove that if $\frac ab$ cannot be simplified further, then $\frac{a-b}{a+b}$ also cannot be simplified further

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility, fractions

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}^{+}$ be numbers with different parity. Prove that if $\frac ab$ cannot be simplified further, then $\frac{a-b}{a+b}$ also cannot be simplified further.

Let $a$ be even, so $a=2k$ and let $b$ be odd, so $b=2k+1$ for any $k \in\mathbb Z$.

We can show that $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{2k}{2k+1}$, which cannot be simplified further.

Then,

$$\frac{a-b}{a+b}=\frac{2k-(2k+1)}{2k+2k+1}=\frac{1}{4k+1}$$

and from this we can clearly see that expression $\frac{a-b}{a+b}$ cannot be simplified further.
Is this a correct approach?

Comment: What do you mean by   "$a/b$ are coprime integers"?

Comment: I mean that $a/b$ cannot be simplified further.

Comment: That’s not what coprime means.  You mean that the numerator and denominator are coprime.

Comment: I apologize, I edited the question.

Comment: Do $a$ and $b$ have to be consecutive then?

Comment: They have to be numbers of different parity. I used $2k+1$ and $2k$ to show this.

Comment: You can't use the same $k$ then it should be $2k+1$ and $2m$ for example.

Comment: From [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question): "**Your question should be clear without the title.** After the title has drawn someone's attention to the question by giving a good description, its purpose is done. **The title is not the first sentence of your question**, so make sure that the question body does not rely on specific information in the title."

Comment: @TonyK, oh, that restriction is not in the body of the question. I missed it in the title. Thanks. Sorry for the noise.

Comment: @Ihf +1. I also missed this point and got downvote. Then, I added the proof to my answer.  Initially, I had stated that the problem was wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you mean $\frac ab$ is the lowest term, then your attempt is not correct. The correct attempt can be considered as follows:

"Let, $a=2m,\thinspace b=2n-1$ or $a=2m-1,\thinspace b=2n$ where $m,n\in\mathbb Z^{+}.$

But, we can continue in a simpler way:

---

Suppose that,

$$\gcd(a-b,a+b)=k,\thinspace k>1$$

where $\gcd(a,b)=1$ and $a,b$ have different parity with $k=2z-1, \thinspace z\in\mathbb Z^{+}$. Then we have,

$$a-b=mk, ~a+b=nk$$

where $\gcd(m,n)=1$.

If $k≥3$ and $k=2z-1,\thinspace z\in\mathbb Z^{+}$, then we conclude that

$$2a=k(m+n)\implies k\mid a\\
2b=k(n-m)\implies k\mid b$$

This means $\gcd(a,b)≥k>1$, which gives a contradiction.

Comment: But then $a$ and $b$ don't have different parity. So the statement is correct.

Comment: @TonyK The word "different parity" was just in the title of the question and I missed it, unfortunately.  I just concentrated on the content of the question. Thank you for point.

Comment: @TonyK I got a quick downvote, but still good because I didn't get too many $\ddot\smile$.

Comment: I apologize for my bad formatting and thank you for your answer. Helped me a lot!

Comment: @wizard844 You're welcome ( ◜‿◝ )

Comment: The person who downvoted my answers, the moderators will catch you one day.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with your answer is this:

One can say

- If $a$ is even then $a = 2k$ for **some** integer $k$.

and

- If $b$ is odd then $b = 2k+1$ for **some** integer $k$.

**BUT** the $k$'s involved are not necessarily the same.

Take $a = 6$ and $b=11$, for $a$ we have $6=2\times 3$ so here $k$ is $3$ and for $b$ we have $11 = 2\times 5 + 1$ so now $k$ is $5$. It's a different $k$.

For obvious reasons is a very bad idea to use the same letter to represent both values.

So what one needs to do is pick a different letter: $a = 2k$, $b=2l+1$ for some integers $k$ and $l$.

Another problem is that been of different parity mean $a$ is even and $b$ is odd **or $a$ is odd and $b$ is even** and you didn't even mention the second case.

Answer (score 0):

Proof by contrapositive is quick.

If $p|a+b,a-b$ then $p|2a$ and $p|2b$.

If $p \nmid 2$ then
$p|a,b$ and $\frac{a}{b}$ can be simplified further.

If $p|2, p=2$ so from before, $2|a+b \implies a+b = 2k \implies a,b$ are the same parity which contradicts our assumption.